# Ошибка в Symfony2 при РНР 5.4

Tags: php, symfony2

Помогите, может кто сталкивался уже... вот тестовый проект https://github.com/dmitxe/Learn-Symfony пытаемся сделать ручками аутентификацию и авторизацию с хранением юзеров и ролей в БД, а в ответ на РНР 5.4 получаем ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\User::getRole() in R:\www\Learn-Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy.php on line 47
```

А на РНР 5.3 всё идеально гладко.

Для установки тестовых данных надо выполнить
`php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load`

Затем пытаемся зайти в раздел `/admin/`
логин/пароль: `john.doe/admin`

Answer (score 1):

В общем то [ларчик](https://github.com/dmitxe/Learn-Symfony/pull/6) просто открывался :)

Проблема видимо в том, что внутри модели роли хранятся в виде `ArrayCollection`, но метод `getRoles()` должен возвращать обычный массив т.к. сам `ArrayCollection` видимо не сериализуется вообще :( а по каким причинам старый код работал в 5.3 уже не улавливаю :)